# visualSVN: Creating separate repositories for different versions of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, repository, branch, visualsvn

I've been working on a project with VisualSVN and Visual Studio 2010 for some time.

I recently upgraded my version of VisualSVN that supports Visual Studio 2012. I manually copied the project (that is not yet hooked into VisualSVN) to Visual Studio 2012 while keeping the old one.

I want to create a repo for the VS2012 version without colliding with the current 2010 version. I tried creating the new repo in a subfolder of the old one by copying the old one to a subfolder (using the repo browser from VS2010) and creating the new one in a subfolder itself (from VS2012). VisualSVN (or TortoiseSVN...) complained that the attempted location is in a previously created repo.

On local storage my file structure is:

```
/[Project Name]/Development/VS2010/[all files and folders]
/[Project Name]/Development/VS2012/[all files and folders]
```

I'd like to keep this structure in the repo.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "solved" the problem by setting up TWO repositories:

```
/[Project Name]2010/[all files and folders]
/[Project Name]2012/[all files and folders]
```

This is a last-ditch effort. My original intent was to create branches under the Project, but that would interfere with the fact that the solution files are totally different content-wise but named exactly the same.